# Riemann tensor definition

Tags: general-relativity

> I have two definitions of the Riemann tensor which are
>   $$\Large R^{\rho}_{\,\,\,\sigma\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}\Gamma^{\rho}_{\nu\sigma}-\partial_{\nu}\Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\sigma}+\Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\lambda}\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu\sigma}-\Gamma^{\rho}_{\nu\lambda}\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\sigma}=R_{\nu\mu\sigma}^{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\rho}$$

But can someone demonstrate how these two ways of writing the Riemann tensor are equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

The fact follows from the two identites of the Riemann tensor: $R_{ijkl}=R_{klij}=-R_{lkij}=R_{lkji}$. Now, $R_{jkl}^i =g^{im} R_{mjkl}$ and ${R_{jkl }}^i=g^{im}R_{jklm }$.

With that you should be able to get the result.

---

You can use the Riemann if you want. However, for 3D spaces, the Ricci is enough. Anyway, given the metric, remember that the expression for the Christoffel symbols is $$\Gamma_{ijk}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k} + \frac{\partial g_{ik}}{\partial x^j} - \frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial x^i} \right) .$$ Moreover, your metric is diagonal ($g=diag(u^2+v^2,u^2+v^2,u^2v^2$). Hence some of the Christoffel symbols are $0$.

By the way, your space seems a 2D surface. In this case, according to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor), the Riemann is given in coordinates just by $$R_{ijkl}= K(g_{ik}g_{kl}-g_{il}g_{jk}),$$ where $K$ is the [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature)

Comment: Oh thank you very much for your answer. It makes perfect sense now. I have that
$$\Large R^{\rho}_{\,\,\,\sigma\mu\nu} = g^{\rho\lambda}R_{\lambda\sigma\mu\nu}=g^{\rho\lambda}R_{\mu\nu\lambda\sigma}=-g^{\rho\lambda}R_{\nu\mu\lambda\sigma}=g^{\rho\lambda}R_{\nu\mu\sigma\lambda} = R_{\nu\mu\sigma}^{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\rho}$$

Comment: So now if I have the line element
$$\Large ds^2 = (u^2+v^2)(du^2+dv^2) + u^2v^2d\phi^2$$
how would I find the Riemann tensor for this $3$ dimensional problem? I know that the fourth index repeats but I just wanna know how it looks so I can do the computations. Would it be something like 
$$\Large R^{u}_{\,\,\,uv\phi},\quad R^{v}_{\,\,\,uv\phi},\quad R^{\phi}_{\,\,\,uv\phi}$$

Comment: Wait apparently I need to use the Ricci tensor for a $3$-D tensor problem but there is no explanation how to choose the indices to find the the non-zero components...

Comment: @MRT: I have added mor information to my answer traying to clarify your comments.

Comment: oh it is in $3$-D because it's in $\mathbb{E}^3$ space. I read your answer but it doesn't quite get to what I was asking. I do have all of the Christoffel components but I just don't know how to find the Ricci tensor.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The Ricci tensor is the thrace of the Riemann: $$R_{ij}= R_{ikj}^k = g^{kl}R_{likj} .$$